# Retrieve contact list name and members via Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-contacts

I'm trying to retrieve "contact lists" (distribution lists) from a Microsoft 365 account using the Graph API and direct http calls.  Right now I use this URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userid}/contactfolders/{folderid}/contacts?$top=500&$count=true
```

This does retrieve the various contacts I have, but not the names of any contact lists or their members. The "count" of items that is retrieved does include those contact lists but not their actual data.

I have tried the "people" and "groups" endpoints but those retrieve different information, not what I am looking for.

I know I can use EWS for this purpose, and I have, but I'm trying to convert my existing application to 100% Graph. I would appreciate any information, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've sent a [user voice](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform/label-name/Microsoft%20Graph) requesting for this feature: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/fetch-contact-group-using-graph-api/idi-p/3262621

Do support if you think there's no feature currently available in Graph API to fetch contact list!